# composed boolean for checking undefined or null

Tags: typescript

I have a composed computed boolean of possible `undefined` or `null` values. Even though checking if the composed boolean is true, typescript doesn't understand that the values cannot be `undefined` or `null` anymore.

In the following example, the type of `alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined || anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined` inside the if branch is evaluated to possibly undefined, which results in error `Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`, but I am already checking `alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined` and `anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined` in `noNullOrUndefined`.

```js
const maybeNullOrUndefined: string | undefined | null = undefined;
const anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined: string | undefined | null = undefined;
const alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined: string | undefined | null = undefined;

const anyFun = (str: string) => { }

const noNullOrUndefined = (anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined || alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined) && maybeNullOrUndefined;

if (noNullOrUndefined) {
    anyFun(maybeNullOrUndefined);
    anyFun(alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined || anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined); // Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
}
```

That's just a constructed example, but in my case, even `maybeNullOrUndefined` is evaluated to be possibly of type undefined, even though I am checking it in a boolean before. Why is that and how can I overcome this?

- TS: v4.7.4
- TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJ4CMCmA5ArgGxweQCcBVMAEzQDMBLMNMgLhmkNoHMYAfGLcq2+lxhhcOGAF4efGnTIBuAFChIsBGBBQAFmkIBZZOmx4ipCjPpMW7IbzMCyQkXglS7sxcugwEOKDrAIUNQAbmgAKiAAgupaOvqomKIm0vaWUKxgHNy2-LKOoi455vIKSuBeakgAYrwuABQsaRlsAJQSAHwwAN4wAL6lnrDqRgQkKXmSdWoa2noGicZjboKc3D5+hAFBoRHRM3HzI8nLZG0AZGfwh0lLufSKCtSUMHXDN6Z3p90KML-eYNVeHVEAkjrdii1FH9-oCwFNfP5AiFwlEYrN4oZ3uMVms0QdQViTpCFP0gA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS will not narrow the type based on conditions like that.

You need to define a new variable and use a branch to call your function. You have 2 options here:

```
const finalVal = alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined || anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined

if (finalVal) {
 anyFun(finalVal);
}
```

or

```
const finalVal = alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined || anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined

finalVal && anyFun(finalVal)
```

You can see this in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJ4CMCmA5ArgGxweQCcBVMAEzQDMBLMNMgLhmkNoHMYAfGLcq2+lxhhcOGAF4efGnTIBuAFChIsBGBBQAFmkIBZZOmx4ipCjPpMW7IbzMCyQkXglS7sxcugwEOKDrAIUNQAbmgAKiAAgupaOvqomKIm0vaWUKxgHNy2-LKOoi455vIKSuBeakgAYrwuABQsaRlsAJQSAHwwAN4wAL6lnrDqRgQkKXmSdWoa2noGicZjboKc3D5+hAFBoRHRM3HzI8nLZG0AZGfwh0lLufSKCtSUMHXDN6Z3p90KML-eYNVeHVEAkjrdii1FH8YD8-oMYDIfPV1v5AiFwlEYrN4oZ3uMVmssQdQXiTi1Yb9EWILv9AWA6lTIQp+kA)

Comment: What is different in doing `const someVar = a || b; if(someVar) ...` and `if(a||b)...`?

Comment: The difference is in the complexity of analysis for doing this correctly.  You are using one variable and then using another variable to make the call. TS would need to make sure these 2 (3 in your case) variable aren't changed between the calls. A task that is very difficult to do. Imagine that after your check, you change the value of a and/or b. TS would need to catch this case and flag it as such. That's why it just does analysis for each var on it's own.

Comment: So if I were to check existence of either variable inside `finalVal`, I would still have to check finalVar *everywhere* it's used before actually using it

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This should be fixed in v4.4, as per changelog (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html). Check for the example of function `function doSomeCheck`. I am using this in Vue, so maybe the vue ts compiler is interrupting here.

Comment: No, it is not fixed in 4.4 You playground is already using 4.7 and it's failing. They you write the condition is very important. The TS analysis works in their case because they are using &&. You example is using || and that's not covered. You can check this by replacing const noNullOrUndefined = (anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined || alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined) && maybeNullOrUndefined; with const noNullOrUndefined = (anotherMaybeNullOrUndefined && alternativeToAnotherMaybeNullOrUndefined) && maybeNullOrUndefined;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246101/discussion-between-radu-di-and-prohit).